# Losing hidden field during page build in MVC 3

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, hidden-field

I have a page which is basically a three stage wizard. I have created a class to hold all the fields on the page and hide 2 of three DIVs making them visible in turn.
I use a variable called "wiz" to track which stage I'm at.

> Apply for travel pass stage 2 of 3

However, even though the label displays the correct value from the controller..

```
'
' POST: /Apply
<HttpPost()>
Function Apply(ByVal mdl As ApplyViewData, ByVal postbutton As Integer) As ActionResult
..
mdl.wiz = 2
..
Return View(mdl)
End Function
```

.. the hidden field underneath holds a different value! I cannot see what is causing this.

```
<h2>Apply for travel pass stage 2 of 3</h2>

<form action="/Pass/Apply" method="post">

<input id="wiz" name="wiz" type="hidden" value="1" />
<input id="client_address" name="client_address" type="hidden" value="" />
<input id="client_name" name="client_name" type="hidden" value="" />
```

Which makes no sense looking at the View source.

```
<h2>Apply for travel pass stage @Model.wiz of 3</h2>

@Code
    Html.BeginForm()
End Code

@Html.Hidden("wiz", Model.wiz)
@Html.Hidden("client_address", Model.client_address)
@Html.Hidden("client_name", Model.client_name)

@Html.ValidationSummary()
```

Why is the wiz variable displayed as 2 but held as 1 hidden? I'm stumped.

Here's the class used.

```
Public Class ApplyViewData
    Private m_client_id As Long
    Private m_apply_date As Date
    Private m_pass_type As Long
    Private m_client_search As String
    Private m_search_archived As Boolean
    Private m_client_name As String
    Private m_client_address As String
    Private m_proof_of_age As Long
    Private m_proof_of_address As Long
    Private m_photocard As Long
    Private m_ethnicity_id As Long
    Private m_new_pass As Boolean
    Private m_wiz As Integer

Public Property client_id() As Long
    Set(value As Long)
        m_client_id = value
    End Set
    Get
        Return m_client_id
    End Get
End Property
Public Property apply_date() As Date
    Set(value As Date)
        m_apply_date = value
    End Set
    Get
        Return m_apply_date
    End Get
End Property
Public Property pass_type() As Long
    Set(value As Long)
        m_pass_type = value
    End Set
    Get
        Return m_pass_type
    End Get
End Property
Public Property client_search() As String
    Set(value As String)
        m_client_search = value
    End Set
    Get
        Return m_client_search
    End Get
End Property
Public Property search_archived() As Boolean
    Set(value As Boolean)
        m_search_archived = value
    End Set
    Get
        Return m_search_archived
    End Get
End Property
Public Property client_name() As String
    Set(value As String)
        m_client_name = value
    End Set
    Get
        Return m_client_name
    End Get
End Property
Public Property client_address() As String
    Set(value As String)
        m_client_address = value
    End Set
    Get
        Return m_client_address
    End Get
End Property
Public Property proof_of_age() As Long
    Set(value As Long)
        m_proof_of_age = value
    End Set
    Get
        Return m_proof_of_age
    End Get
End Property
Public Property proof_of_address() As Long
    Set(value As Long)
        m_proof_of_address = value
    End Set
    Get
        Return m_proof_of_address
    End Get
End Property
Public Property photocard() As Long
    Set(value As Long)
        m_photocard = value
    End Set
    Get
        Return m_photocard
    End Get
End Property
Public Property ethnicity_id() As Long
    Set(value As Long)
        m_ethnicity_id = value
    End Set
    Get
        Return m_ethnicity_id
    End Get
End Property
Public Property new_pass() As Boolean
    Set(value As Boolean)
        m_new_pass = value
    End Set
    Get
        Return m_new_pass
    End Get
End Property
Public Property wiz() As Integer
    Set(value As Integer)
        m_wiz = value
    End Set
    Get
        Return m_wiz
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing the same problem as another person from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958390/value-using-html-extension-is-different-than-what-it-is-supposed-to-be-if-two-mo/13958559#13958559). Take a look at the accepted answer and comments to it since they are relevant to your issue.

In your case you might only need to remove value from `ModelState` for the key `wiz`.